# Uploading from client to server is slow, but downloading to server from client is fast

Tags: networking, raid

I hope someone can shed light as to where I should focus my efforts.

I have several clients connected to a domain through a Windows 2008 server.  A few days ago, the applications on the client computers which store data on the server started to lag significantly.

**If I sit down at a client machine**... I get:

100+MBs downloads from server

100+MBs downloads from other clients

***5MBs uploads to server*** *

However...

**If I sit down at the server**... I get:

***50+MBs downloads from clients*** *

50MBs is acceptable, but 5MBs is not.  What could be causing the difference in speeds in this case?  There is a RAID1 configuration on the server, so I expect to see a drop in write times to that disk array.  But the write speed of the drives does not account for the 45MBs discrepancy experienced depending on where the transfer is initiated (client or server).

If I plug a USB drive into the server, share it, and attempt to copy a file from a client to that USB drive (client-initiated transfer), I get slightly better speeds, up to 30MBs (vs 5MBs).  If however, while that transfer is taking place, I attempt to upload to the RAID controlled volumes, both transfers (to the USB drive and to the local disk) top out at around 5MBs.

According to the Dell diagnostics, there are no issues with the drives in the RAID array.  Disabling the firewall on the server does not help.

So what gives?  Could it be an overloaded or malfunctioning switch?  Working on the server, the UI is slow to respond, but I don't see any heavy memory or CPU loads.  The only thing I see of interest are the 14 page faults produced by mmc.exe every minute.

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions you might have to help me figure this out.

Comment: SSD's or Spinning media?  Any SMART drive details?

Comment: Spinning.  SMART diagnosis is 'OK'.  Still, the performance of the server UI is questionable.

Comment: Could it be a switch problem?  Copying files locally slow?  Run some diagnostics on the server:   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.08.pulse.aspx

Comment: Could be.  I unplugged all of the switches for 5 minutes.  Copying a file to the same partition on the server is indeed much slower than copying a file from the network or a separate partition, ~15MBs. I did run the Dell-provided diagnostics from the bios, but nothing came of it.

Comment: Could it be a corruption on the FS?  Reboot and fix errors if you dare?  back up first.

Comment: I have rebooted a few times.  I suppose I'll have to wait until their work hours end before I can really dig into it.  The last time I tried, I ended up taking their system down until the raid array synced back up.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, I would run a LAN speed test. My favorite app is:

[TotuSoft's LAN Speed test](http://totusoft.com/lanspeed)

and try the transfer with and without windows caching.

I would also try another protocol, e.g., ftp.  This way you can have a better idea if it's a network issue or a Windows fs issue.

(If the server is pending updates, please install and restart before starting tests).

Comment: Using another protocol is a great suggestion.  I thought to do that, but only after I had left the site.  That program will seemingly come in handy as well.  Thank you.  I will report back tomorrow or this weekend.

Comment: Windows fs issue?  ftp still reads/writes to the windows fs!  But maybe you meant to say maybe smb fs issue.

Comment: Matt, I sure wish I was working with a dual-booting server.  In that case, I could keep everything constant other than the Windows OS.

Comment: Matt, it's a question of semantics, but if you want to get legal about, if the problem is smb --> FS <--, as you stated, then that --> FS <-- is part of the greater Windows FS, and the statement is still correct.  Since Dustin isn't reporting local disk speed issues the part of the Windows FS that accesses the local disk is likely not the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using CIFS for all of this, but it hasn't been stated. Also, I'm assuming that you're creating a CIFS share on the client and connecting to that as a method to test "server from client" download. When considering network filesystem performance, it is very important to know which protocol so that we know how it behaves under different environmental conditions.

CIFS has *terrible* performance over lossy links, and absolutely does not tolerate jitter in the best of times. If you're using bonding on your server, you must utilize LACP or active-backup (or similar) as a LAG method, or you may be introducing jitter (which has more impact during write than read when using CIFS).

With this in mind, and realizing that you're describing a consistently poor CIFS write speed, problems with channel bonding on the server are likely a culprit (if not simply an independently faulty switch). If you're using bonding, make sure you're using a mode and algorithm that works well with CIFS.

Since you state that this problem recently showed up, a faulty switch is quite likely (if nobody has changed relevant switch side settings). "Dirty" network links can greatly affect the speed of data disassembly / reassembly on the switch, introducing potential jitter and lossiness.

Check link error counters on the switch (if it's capable of that), and check counters on the client and server NICs as well. Jitter and loss will always be reported (though they are not the only players in this equation). Use a LAN speed test as @panos415 suggested to get more metrics, and to possibly increment counters.